# add a git merge driver and make it default

Tags: git, git-merge

I've written a custom merge driver, that applies to all the work I'm doing across a number of repos.

Rather than have a .gitattributes in each repo, I was wondering if there was a global way to specify that all files should use my custom merge driver?

Answer (score 0):

The custom merge driver is declare in a `.gitattributes` file, and this is for *one* repo (pushed / pulled across upstream repos with the *same* history: clones)

But this isn't for *different* repos (ie, with different history), even you you grouped those different repos as submodules of one parent repo (which would contains said `.gitattributes` file): the attributes declared in that file would go over the submodules and would be limited to the parent repo.